# Difference between ^(.*)$ and ^ in regular Expressions (.htaccess)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What's the difference between:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/page.html   [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/page.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real difference between those 2 rules but I prefer the first rule for simplicity.

Since you're not doing anything with the REQUEST_URI from the matched group there is no need to capture it as you're doing in your second rule using `^(.*)$`

Difference is in regex pattern:

```
^      - means match line start (will always match)
^(.*)$ - means match whole URI with 0 or more characters and capture it in $1
```

Comment: Generally the only reason for a regular expression to have a capturing block `(…)` is if that match is going to be used in the replacement. For example to prefix every URL with `/foo` you would start with something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: +1 Everyone should take a basic course on `regex` before diving in the `mod_rewrite` pool :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: Really sound advise

Answer (score 3):

As anubhava noted - there is no difference in your context, also `^` should match faster, since it doesn't have to parse till the end of line `$` and doesn't have to store anything in `$1` variable.